# JasperReports: Field Date

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to learn `JasperReports` on some online tutorial sites but I cant seem to make this simple snippet work.

I wanted to select a date field from my DB and pass it into my jrxml file.

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="ToolDemo"
              columnCount="2"
              columnWidth="240" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792">
    <import value="java.util.Date"/>

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select a.id, a.date_acquired from tools a where a.country = 'Oceania']]>
    </queryString>

    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date_acquired" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

But I cant get pass the filling process and I am having an error: `Unable to get value for field date_acquired of class "java.util.Date"`.  I tried making use of import tag also.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied your report template, create sample MySql database with one table

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| a_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Then I inserted one row:

```
insert into tools(id, a_date) values('1', '2010-05-01');
```

Test query:

```
mysql> select * from tools;
+------+------------+
| id   | a_date     |
+------+------------+
| 1    | 2010-05-01 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

After that I used your template and tested it under iReport tool. Just open you report using iReport.

Your report template with little modifications:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="java.util.Date"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT a.id, a.a_date FROM tools a]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="a_date" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[$F{a_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Using mysql database connection and report template i tested report generation under iReport and it works fine.

Are you sure that field "date_acquired" is type of DATE (or another format for dates in your database) in database? I recommend you to use iReport fore report template generation. It's very useful and prevent you from writing a lot of "boring" code. Also, it could helps you to create report fields from sql query and test it using real database.

Comment: .  I will study this iReport thing and try it out.  I actually am still understanding the details of JasperReports.  I have read that its a good thing to learn the details of Jasperreport before using the GUI tool (iReport).  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You are absolutely right about using GUI tool, but it can help you to see mistakes. iReport simplifies testing cases.